# How to make apk in react-native after changes in react-navigation folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I am facing problem while making apk in react-native app. I had made changes in node_modules->react-navigation folder for making background.Now when I make apk, it's not showing any changes which I made in that folder. Guide me how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AndroidStudio:
`Build > Clean Project`

Or in your android folder run this command: `./gradlew clean`

and then rebuild your project.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I did.. But still same problem. Background Image i add in react_navigation is not showing..